# How would I get a certain part of a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's an example string:

```
survey_questions_attributes_1317784471568_answers_attributes
```

I want to get the `1317784471568` out of the string.

But that part could also be text. For example, I may also need to get a string called `new_questions` from that same spot in the string.

The constant here is that `survey_questions_attributes_` will always precede the chunk I want and `_answers_attributes` will always follow it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
id = str.match(/_questions_attributes_(.+)_answers_attributes/)[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = "survey_questions_attributes_1317784471568_answers_attributes";

var newStr = str.replace("survey_questions_attributes_", "");
newStr = newStr.replace("_answers_attributes", "");
```

Easiest way I can think of without using regular expressions or the like.

Answer (score 1):

Try -

```
var text = "survey_questions_attributes_1317784471568_answers_attributes"
      .replace("survey_questions_attributes_","")
      .replace("_answers_attributes","")
```

Answer (score -1):

Use substring():

```
mystring = "survey_questions_attributes_1317784471568_answers_attributes"
newstring = mystring.substring(28, 41)
```

Comment: That requires the thing to be found to be of a constant length, which may be an incorrect assumption.

Comment: The original question states that the strings surrounding the numbers are "constant".